# Помогите собрать фильтр массива объектов js

Tags: javascript

Общая суть сайта(скрипта) выводить список рецептов из имеющихся ингредиентов в наличии. Все работает но столкнулся с такой мыслью что бурбон и виски по "сути" одно и тоже и стоило бы выводить рецепт имея или виски или бурбон но сейчас фильтр жестко привязан к конкретному ингредиенту, вопрос как сделать фильтр так чтоб рецепт выводился если есть виски или бурбон и это можно было как то указать в объекте рецепта с сохранением приоритета если есть оба напитка?

Имеем подобный массив

```
recipes = [
  {
    name: "Название1",
    img: ".jpg",
    ingr: ["whiskey", "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"],
    size: ["30", "30", "15", "15", "120", "g150", " "], 
    description: "описание"
  },
  {
    name: "Название2",
    img: ".jpg",
    ingr: ["bourbon", "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"],
    size: ["30", "30", "15", "15", "120", "g150", " "], 
    description: "описание"
  },
]
//этот массив содержит ингредиенты в наличии
b = ["bourbon", "whiskey", "liquor_triple_sec","lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"];
//сам фильтр 
const res = recipes.filter(({ ingr }) => ingr.every(v => b.indexOf(v) !== -1));
```

Моя хотелка выглядит так, но js выбирает просто первое значение из или. Логика: есть только бурбон показывает 2 рецепта с бурбоном, если есть и виски и бурбон показывает 2 рецепта но один с бурбоном а другой с виски как указано в рецепте что первый напиток важнее

```
recipes = [
  {
    name: "Название1",
    img: ".jpg",
    ingr: [("bourbon" || "whiskey"), "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"],
    size: ["30", "30", "15", "15", "120", "g150", " "], 
    description: "описание"
  },
  {
    name: "Название2",
    img: ".jpg",
    ingr: [("whiskey" || "bourbon"), "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"],
    size: ["30", "30", "15", "15", "120", "g150", " "], 
    description: "описание"
  },
]
```

*.includes() запрещен сайт крутиться на телевизоре он его не понимает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой вариант с небольшой модификацией объекта и кода. Альтернативные ингредиенты указываются в виде строки, разделенной `|`. При фильтрации такие строки режутся по разделителю и проверяется наличие хотя бы одного элемента. Приоритетность элемента внутри строки определяется порядком их следования, но данным кодом это не обрабатывается, это для бармена.

```js
recipes = [{
    name: "Название1",
    img: ".jpg",
    ingr: ["bourbon|whiskey", "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"],
    size: ["30", "30", "15", "15", "120", "g150", " "],
    description: "описание"
  },
  {
    name: "Название2",
    img: ".jpg",
    ingr: ["whiskey|bourbon", "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"],
    size: ["30", "30", "15", "15", "120", "g150", " "],
    description: "описание"
  },
  {
    name: "Название3",
    img: ".jpg",
    ingr: ["tequila|rum", "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"],
    size: ["30", "30", "15", "15", "120", "g150", " "],
    description: "описание"
  }
]

b = ["bourbon", "whiskey", "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"];
const res = recipes.filter(({
  ingr
}) => ingr.every(v => v.split('|').reduce((acc, curr) => acc + (b.indexOf(curr) !== -1), 0)));
console.log(res);
```

Если необходимо оставить только один приоритетный элемент из имеющихся в наличии ингредиентов, код может быть таким. Здесь сначала перебираются все рецепты, перед обработкой каждого устанавливается флаг `absent=true` (предполагаем, что исходно все ингредиенты есть). Далее перебираются все ингредиенты, которые сначала "сплитятся", а потом фильтруются - если какие-то из них есть, то формируется массив ненулевой длины, где элементы расположены в порядке следования (приоритета) - забираем первый, самый приоритетный элемент. Если же ни одного из ингредиентов нет, то устанавливается флаг `absent=false`. Далее в зависимости от состояния этого флага весь рецепт либо заносится в результирующий массив, либо нет. Если заносится, то предварительно меняется массив ингредиентов в нем на актуализированный с учетом их наличия и приоритетности.

```js
recipes = [{
    name: "Название1",
    img: ".jpg",
    ingr: ["bourbon|whiskey", "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"],
    size: ["30", "30", "15", "15", "120", "g150", " "],
    description: "описание"
  },
  {
    name: "Название2",
    img: ".jpg",
    ingr: ["whiskey|bourbon", "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"],
    size: ["30", "30", "15", "15", "120", "g150", " "],
    description: "описание"
  },
  {
    name: "Название3",
    img: ".jpg",
    ingr: ["tequila|rum", "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"],
    size: ["30", "30", "15", "15", "120", "g150", " "],
    description: "описание"
  }
]

b = ["bourbon", "whiskey", "liquor_triple_sec", "lemon_juice", "sugar_syrup", "sprite", "ice", "bild"];

let res = [];
recipes.forEach(rec => {
  inglist = [];
  absent = false;
  rec.ingr.forEach(i => {
    f = i.split('|').filter(el => b.indexOf(el) !== -1)
    if (f.length > 0) inglist.push(f[0]);
    else absent = true;
  })
  if (!absent) {
    rec.ingr = inglist;
    res.push(rec);
  }
})
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! второй вариант хорош!